# Disable a given manual job for previous pipelines

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have this proof-of-concept (just displaying the relevant parts) in a GitLab CI pipeline:

```yaml
deploy:development:
  stage: deploy
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"
  script: do_deploy
  variables:
    ANSIBLE_INVENTORY: development

deploy:test:
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: test
    url: https://env.url.tld
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"
      when: manual
  script: do_deploy
  variables:
    ANSIBLE_INVENTORY: test
```

I would like to disable/deprecate the previous `deploy:test` jobs when a new one is created. Basically, the `deploy:test` job should only be enabled for the current/latest pipeline, hence preventing an old build to take over a recent one.

> I'm not saying that it should happens instantaneously; if it's running, is fine to let if finish, but if it failed and a new one is created, the old one (failed) should be disabled also. Same for the current one, if it ran successfully, it should be disabled — this is an optimal state.

Is there a configuration setting that will let me do that? I have checked **Auto-cancel redundant, pending pipelines** and **Skip outdated deployment jobs** in `Settings > CI/CD > General pipelines`, but still the job doesn't get disabled on previous pipelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have checked Auto-cancel redundant, pending pipelines and Skip outdated deployment jobs in Settings > CI/CD > General pipelines, but still the job doesn't get disabled on previous pipelines.

It should work better with [GitLab 15.5](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/10/22/gitlab-15-5-released/#prevent-outdated-deployment-jobs) (October 2022):

> ### Prevent outdated deployment jobs
>
> Previously, some outdated jobs could be manually started or retried even when `Skip outdated deployment jobs` is enabled.
>
> **We have updated the logic for this setting to check the deployment status when a job starts**.
>
> The job does not execute if the deployment job is outdated due to a more recent deployment.
> This check ensures that outdated deployment jobs are not accidentally started, overwriting more recent code changes in production.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/deployment_safety.html#prevent-outdated-deployment-jobs) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/363328).

Answer (score 2):

Did you try adding the "interruptible" tag?

[image]

It seems like you have to add `interruptible: true` to your yaml.

For example:

```yaml
deploy:development:
  stage: deploy
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"
  script: do_deploy
  interruptible: true
  variables:
    ANSIBLE_INVENTORY: development
```

Ref: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/32022